# device oopswhen module is removed

Tags: android, linux-kernel

When I use LKM to hook syscall about Android Kernel,I get something wrong

but I'm not good at Linux kernel debug,and I want to know how to deal with this problem.The similar problem told me the reason is read is blocked but module has been rmmod,I want to know how to solve this problem.

The reason is I want to monitor the apk's behavior.so I choose hook Linux kernel 3.4.67(goldfish)  and with Android 4.4.4 code complied

Here is My code,when I insmod the module,it really get the action about read sth. But when I rommd the module ,the emulator direct get oops,and I finally find the reason is in my sys_read() hook,because when I hook syscall open ,it's okay.

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include<linux/init.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/semaphore.h>
#include <linux/moduleparam.h>
#include <asm/cacheflush.h>
#include<linux/delay.h>
#include<linux/file.h>
#include<linux/fs.h>
#include<linux/dirent.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("SafeCode han");
void  ** sys_call_table;

asmlinkage int (*original_call_read) (unsigned int, char*, int);
asmlinkage int hack_sys_read(unsigned int fd, char * buf, int count){

if(fd == 0 && count == 1)
{
    printk("something is read aha %s\n", buf);
}

return original_call_read(fd,buf count);

}
int init_module()
{
 //this is my sys_call_table address which found in System.map 
  sys_call_table =(void*)0xc000d984;
  printk(KERN_ALERT "testhahaha\n");
  original_call_read = sys_call_table[__NR_read];
  sys_call_table[__NR_read] = hack_sys_read;
  return 0;
}

/*when I need to rommd my module ,the devices oops..*/
 void cleanup_module()
{
  sys_call_table[__NR_read]=original_call_read;
//sys_call_table[__NR_open]=original_call_open;


}
```

so ,Plz help me~ thanks~,I want to know the depth reason and the solution

Comment: don't point us to other questions. We need to see  your environment and code **in  your question** in order to help. Please update your Q to form a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Good luck.

Comment: @shellter thnks，I'll  modify my question with my own situation

Answer (score 0):

It is unsafe to revert previous value of the syscall's pointer and unload the module, contained replacement code: some process may use your syscall function at this moment, and it will be very upset when its code is gone off. As far as I know, there is no protection against that.

Syscalls are not intended to be changed by kernel modules. Either patch kernel code itself, or do not touch syscalls at all and use some sort of hooks, e.g. kprobes.

Comment: so should I give up this kind of hook method?Can I modify the sysfs interface or other way to get this problem well?@Tsyvarev

Comment: It is dependent from you true purpose. In the code you provide I see only toy example for educational purposes. In that case there is nothing bad to not unload module at all. If you want to collect some statistic about syscall, you may found [SystemTap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/) usefull: It allows you to write program using some scripting language, and automatically transforms your script into kernel module, which uses kprobes.

Comment: how about this question and solution for me ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188865
As Chris Stratton answered ,the blocked read call is the reason,but I really don't know how to solve(by my weak linux kernel knowledge )@Tsyvarev

Comment: Tailing jump to original function instead of calling it may reduce possibility of the problem, but doesn't eliminate it entirely. Also, the question you refer to seems duplicate yours, isn't it?

Comment: that's it,because I hava same question ,and I know what that question said.But confuse that how to do?Did that mean jump to original function(sys_call) in exit_module? @Tsyvarev

Comment: In your implementation, you call `original_call_read` from your `hack_call_read` function. That is, even some thread have already processed beginning of your function and have stepped into the original function, it still needs your function to be existed for correct returning from the system call. There is a technique `tail call` which allows to eliminate such dependency from your code' existence, so it can be safetly unloaded in exit_module. You can read more in this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)

Comment: Thanks a lot,I'll be try.@Tsyvarev